# An R package for simulate time series with different Hurst exponent?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm searching for R packages that it is possible to simulate time series with different Hurst exponent. I need to simulate:

1. anti-persistente time series (0< H<0.5);
2. white noise (H=0.5);
3. persistente time series (0.5< H<1);

Can be useful to only the programmation, not necessary the package (I prefer it that way). I found the R package **arfima**. But a i don't have so much information about the experience involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package `somebm` and function `fbm`

```
library(somebm)

set.seed(123)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

plot(fbm(hurst = 0.01, n = 100)) # anti-persistent
plot(fbm(hurst = 0.5, n = 100))  # Brownian walk
plot(fbm(hurst = 0.99, n = 100)) # Persistent
```

Returns following time series:

[image]

Comment: Ok Lstat, I did it .

Comment: Great! Good luck with your analysis.